# Java reflection invoke method

Tags: java, reflection

I've defined this class that, when executed, it recovers all the methods from the class passes as a parameter to the main method and executes them all:

```
package tec;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class LancerTests {
  static private void lancer(Class c) throws Exception{
    Method methods[] = c.getMethods();
    int nbTest = 0;
    for(Method m : methods){
      m.invoke(c.newInstance());
      System.out.println(".");
      nbTest++;
    }
    System.out.println("(" + nbTest + "):OK: " + c.getName());
  }

  static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean estMisAssertion = false;
    assert estMisAssertion = true;

    if (!estMisAssertion) {
      System.out.println("Execution impossible sans l'option -ea");
      return;
    }

    for(String arg : args){
      Class cls = Class.forName(arg);
      lancer(cls);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at tec.LancerTests.lancer(LancerTests.java:10)
    at tec.LancerTests.main(LancerTests.java:28)
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code.

Edit: This is an example of a class I would like to execute but the error is still there eventhough there's no argument needed:

```
package tec;

 class TestMonteeFatigue{

  public void testChoixPlaceMontee(){
    FauxArret a = new FauxArret();
    MonteeFatigue p = new MonteeFatigue("Jean",5,null);
    FauxVehicule v = new FauxVehicule(FauxVehicule.ASSIS);
    p.choixPlaceMontee(v);
    //assert "monteeDemanderAssis"==getLastLog(v) : "assis";
    v = new FauxVehicule(FauxVehicule.PLEIN);
    p = new MonteeFatigue("Jean",5,null);
    p.choixPlaceMontee(v);
    assert p.estDehors();
  }

  /*protected String getLastLog(FauxVehicule f) {
      return f.logs.get(f.logs.size() -1);
  }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method that you're trying to invoke reflectively is not one that takes no arguments.

```
// snip...

Method methods[] = c.getMethods();
for(Method m : methods){
  System.out.println(m.getName() + " requires " + m.getParameterTypes().length + " arguments");
}
```

Some [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/method.html) takes you through the process, and [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection) has some stuff too

---

edit to add:

To get this running, you can wrap the invoke in a conditional that checks the method doesn't require any arguments

```
if (m.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
  m.invoke(c.newInstance());
}
```

Comment: I edited my question with a class example

Comment: It's probably complaining about the method `getLastLog(FauxVehicule f)` which clearly *does* require an argument.

Comment: If I remove it, the error is still there. I edit my question

Comment: Add the conditional. You're probably also tripping up over built in methods in class `Object` (eg: `boolean equals(Object o)`). If you changed from `c.getMethods()` to `c.getDeclaredMethods()` you'll get a list of the methods that are declared in the class, and not inherited ones. Not sure if that's what you're after

Answer (score 0):

On the method invoke must have the following arguments:

```
method.invoke(class, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)
```

Where class is the method's class and args are the method's arguments.

The problem is that you may be calling a method that requires passing some arguments, and you are passing none.+

Example:

```
public void method1() {
    //DO STUFF
}

public void mehtod2(String parameter) {
   //DO OTHER STUFF
}
```

Then this would happen if you don't specify arguments:

```
method1.invoke(class.newInstance()); //Executes fine
method2.invoke(class.newInstance()); //Exception as it lacks the parameter
method2.invoke(class.newInstance(),"The parameter"); //Executes fine
```

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Is the stacktrace (exception) still the same? Are you only calling this method? If you are calling multiple classes then the error could be on another classe's method.

Answer (score 0):

probably the class you are referring to requires some input parameters that you are missing to send when you call the Method::invoke() method without giving any arguments.

The method signature is as follows:

```java
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
```

As this method accepts `varargs` (the three dots) , it allows you to not send any arguments at all, or send as many as you want...

In your case, you sent none.